# CSS dynamic class

Tags: css

Lets say I have a flex wrapping container with an attribute data-columns like this:

```
<div class="grid" data-columns="2"></div>
```

and

```
.grid {
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
}

.grid[data-columns=2] > * {
    width:50%;
}

.grid[data-columns=3] > * {
    width:33.3%;
}

.grid[data-columns=4] > * {
    width:25%;
}
```

the idea is that the children of .grid class elements have the width of 1 / grid.data-columns. Now i could of course just write a bunch of them but I'm wondering if there is a more dynamic way to do this? Could css actually fetch the number of columns from their parent element and use it in a calculation to determine width?

Comment: One solution is you could use a css preprocessor to generate it out for you. Check out http://lesscss.org/#using-less-usage-in-code. I think that's what you're looking for generally.

Comment: CSS3 had the `attr()` function that might work but it can only get the attribute values of the selected element, not a parent element. Reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#funcdef-attr  You could do this with jQuery/JavaScript

Answer (score -1):

Don't understanding at it all with "Could css actually fetch the number of columns from their parent element and use it in a calculation to determine width?", but if you got, how to say *2* childs with the class "grids_child" in "grid" you can do

```
.grid_child{width:calc(100% / 2);}
```

and that will make all the elements with the ".grid_child" class, to have 50%

I didn't understand your question, but I told you this cause I see the "1 / .grid".

A good choice it to usea the pre-proccessor like someone told you

Answer (score -1):

As Marc said in the comment,

> CSS3 had the attr() function that might work but it can only get the attribute values of the selected element, not a parent element.

and also there's no browser supporting CSS3's `attr()` currently. So it have to be done with external tools such as [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) and [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/).

Here's an example written in LESS:

```
@max: 10;
.col(@index) when (@index =< @max) { // iterate
    .grid[data-columns=@{index}] > * {
        width: percentage(1 / @index);
    }
    .col((@index + 1));
}
.col(@index) when (@index > @max) {} // terminal
.col(1); // kickstart it
```

and this will be translated to

```
.grid[data-columns=1] > * {
  width: 100%;
}
.grid[data-columns=2] > * {
  width: 50%;
}
.grid[data-columns=3] > * {
  width: 33.33333333%;
}

/* ...... */

.grid[data-columns=10] > * {
  width: 10%;
}
```